# Persisting entities to both database and search engine

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, elasticsearch

I am creating an application where I use JPA and ElasticSearch. I have a question on how to structure and hook them together. I have an entity named `Newspaper`.

I want to persist it in the database and also index it in the search engine. Now, what would be a good approach to that? Would you inject the search repository layer into the news paper repository which use JPA and then index it after persisting it?

Would you create a service layer and have a service bean class where you first persist it into the database then index it using the repositories? Or can this be done in other (better) ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did in my former job:

In the service layer, after persisting entity with Hibernate, transform the entity using Jackson and send it to Elasticsearch.
Of course, you can do that in the repo layer (DAO Layer) but I don't like it so much.

By the way, if you are using Spring, have a look at the [Spring factory Project for Elasticsearch](https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch).

Comment: Okey, thank you. That was how I originally planned to do it. Just one question then. Did you have two services? One that persist an entity and another one that persist and indexed? Or did you always want to index so you just created one service?

Comment: Only one service. But with try/catch as I don't want to stop my service if something fails with Elasticsearch. I just need to log the error.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the code from Hibernate Search. It syncs w Lucene and the db at the same time (or async if desired).

Or just use Hibernate Search.

Comment: But I don't want to use Hibernate search. I use Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes, I know. Which is why I suggested you look at the source code for Hibernate Search to see how it works, so you can implement it on your own.

Comment: It doesn't work like it is in my scenario it seems. Question still remains unanswered.